# Save two artifacts from two jobs within a workflow in GH actions for ZAP tool

Tags: github-actions, zap

I have been trying to run both ZAP API scan and ZAP Full scan using GH actions to run within a workflow and generate two different artifacts. However, the yaml script that I have been trying cannot do so.

At the end of it, the two scans should generate "artifact1" and "artifact2" from the scans that is availble to be downloaded into your local dir.

```
name: ZAP Security Scans

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  Full_scans:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      full_scan_result: ${{ steps.store_full_scan_result.outputs.full_scan_result }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: main

      - name: ZAP Full Scan
        id: full_scan
        uses: zaproxy/action-full-scan@v0.9.0
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          docker_name: 'ghcr.io/zaproxy/zaproxy:stable'
          target: 'www.targeturl.com'
      
     - name: Store Full Scan Result
       id: store_full_scan_result
       run: |
         mkdir -p full_scan_results
         mv *.html full_scan_results/ || true
         FULL_RESULT_FILE=$(find full_scan_results -name "*.html" -type f)
         echo "::set-output name=full_scan_result::$FULL_RESULT_FILE"
```

At this point, I want to upload the results of the full scan.

And the workflow continues for API Scan:

```
  API_scan:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      api_scan_result: ${{ steps.store_api_scan_result.outputs.api_scan_result }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: main

      - name: ZAP API Scan
        id: api_scan
        uses: zaproxy/action-api-scan@v0.6.0
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          docker_name: 'ghcr.io/zaproxy/zaproxy:stable'
          format: openapi
          target: 'www.targeturl.com'
          
      - name: Store API Scan Result
        id: store_api_scan_result
        run: |
          mkdir -p api_scan_results
          mv *.html api_scan_results/ || true
          API_RESULT_FILE=$(find api_scan_results -name "*.html" -type f)
          echo "::set-output name=api_scan_result::$API_RESULT_FILE"

  Upload_Artifacts:
    needs:
      - Full_scans
      - API_scan
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Upload Full Scan Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: artifact1
          path: ${{ needs.Full_scans.outputs.full_scan_result }}

      - name: Upload API Scan Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: artifact2
          path: ${{ needs.API_scan.outputs.api_scan_result }}
```

Comment: You said it “cannot do so”. What is the current result or status of your workflow?

Comment: as of now, the workflow runs successfully, but only one result from the fullscan is shown to be downloaded (becasue of the default zap fullscan), nothing from the api scan and other artifact has all the files from my worplace (other .yml, .ignore,  files). During the process, api scan is finished at first and then the full scan, and seems like the scanned results are overwritten.